# Why can't we see repeated values for a continuous distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

> For a continuous distribution, we will never see repeated values so
> the minimum and second smallest, for example, could not take on the
> same value.

Why? Suppose I have a N(0,1) distribution. It's natural for me, say, to hit some point twice.

Comment: It's to do with the fact that $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$ for a continuous rv $X$.

Comment: I know this fact. But it doesn't mean x cannot happen in the data set.

Comment: The relevant phrase is "almost surely". It's certainly *possible* to obtain the same value twice. But this will almost surely not occur: the probability is zero.

Comment: @ChiaoChao: What do you mean by "hit some point twice"?

Comment: @user251257: I mean for example in R, when you run runif(10,0,1). You will observe 10 points from (0,1) uniform distribution. Maybe you will observe two same values, say 0.5.

Comment: @ChiaoChao: yes. But notice these numbers are not really uniformly distributed, in fact they are not even random. They just look like uniformly distributed under particular circumstances. For "real" randomness you need to resort to physical phenomena and you need to take a measurement. That is, you can only observe that a point is in a particular region.

Comment: Let’s think of it as a game of chance. You hit the rand on your calculator (as it is said above, the result is not really random, but anyway) and I extend a bet: hit that rand again! Every time you hit it, you have to pay me 10 dollars. If you get the same number as you got in the first time, I will return to you twice the money you have lost. You can play 1000 rounds. How far are you willing to go in such a game?